# Trying to submit a form using jsoup in android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, jsoup

I am trying to submit a form of a website using jsoup. The problem is when I try to submit the form on web browser, an alert box pops up saying are you sure? Here is the snap of it

[image]

I tried to search everything to submit popup but couldn't find anything.

here is the code so far

```
package com.example.ebad.apppw;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class course_registration_post extends Activity {

    String url = "http://111.68.99.8/StudentProfile/RegisterCourse.aspx";
    HashMap<String, String> hashMaps;

    Button button;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.temp);

        hashMaps = Data.map;

        button  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new course_post().execute();

            }
        });


    }


    private class course_post extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try
            {

                Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect(url).method(Connection.Method.GET).timeout(4000).execute();
                Document document = loginForm.parse();


                String viewstate2 = document.select("input[name=__VIEWSTATE]").attr("value");
                String stategenerator2 = document.select("input[name=__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR]").attr("value");
                String Eventvalidation2 = document.select("input[name=__EVENTVALIDATION]").attr("value");

                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                        .cookies(hashMaps)
                        .data("__EVENTTARGET", "")
                        .data("__EVENTARGUMENT", "")
                        .data("__VIEWSTATE", viewstate2)
                        .data("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", stategenerator2)
                        .data("__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED","")
                        .data("__EVENTVALIDATION", Eventvalidation2)
                        .data("ctl00$Body$COURSES_OFFERED$ctl06$cbox","on")
                        .data("ctl00$Body$RegisterButton", "Register Selected Courses")
                        .post();

  /*              JSContext context = new JSContext();
                String script =
                        "function factorial(x) { var f = 1; for(; x > 1; x--) f *= x; return f; }\n" +
                                "var fact_a = factorial(a);\n";
                context.evaluateScript(script);
*/
                String s = doc.select("span[id=ctl00_MessageLabel]").text();

                System.out.println(doc);


                System.out.println(viewstate2);
                System.out.println(stategenerator2);
                System.out.println(Eventvalidation2);
                System.out.println(s);


            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();}


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the code of alert box I found on webiste

[image]

I have tried everything to make it work but I don't know what I am doing wrong. It would be really helpful if you guy help me solve this problem.

Here is the final state

```
__EVENTTARGET:
__EVENTARGUMENT:
__VIEWSTATE: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
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR:1DA4211B
__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED:
__EVENTVALIDATION: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
ctl00$Body$RegisterButton:Register Selected Courses
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Jsoup cannot handle javascript. You need a headless browser for (selenium). But there might be a way. Can you provide the website?

Comment: @alkis here is the [link](http://111.68.99.8/StudentProfile/)

Comment: Oh wow, there is a lot going on behind the scenes. You can do this, login with your browser. Before you do that, open the chrome dev tools and check the request (Network tab). This request (post) will contain all the available data you must include too. Moreover you have to make the request to the same url that you see in the `Network` tab. With this much javascript running it wouldn't surprise me if this is altered too, but in the request you will see everything at their final state.

Comment: @alkis I have edited the question with the final state

Comment: You need the `Request` headers of RegisterCourse.aspx. Don't forget to hide username/password

Comment: @alkis I have added the photo and edited again but can you tell me how can I grab these headers and post it or anything I am kind of stuck at it

Comment: Include in your request the Cookie, User agent and all the form data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101225/discussion-between-ebad-khan-and-alkis).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup
        .connect("http://111.68.99.8/StudentProfile/")
        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
        .userAgent(
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.0 Safari/537.36")
        .execute();

Document loginDoc = loginForm.parse();
String viewstate2 = loginDoc.select("input[name=__VIEWSTATE]").attr(
        "value");
String stategenerator2 = loginDoc.select(
        "input[name=__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR]").attr("value");
String Eventvalidation2 = loginDoc.select(
        "input[name=__EVENTVALIDATION]").attr("value");

Document document = Jsoup
        ..userAgent(
                    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.0 Safari/537.36")
        .connect("http://111.68.99.8/StudentProfile/RegisterCourse.aspx")
        .data("__EVENTTARGET", "").data("__EVENTARGUMENT", "")
        .data("__VIEWSTATE", viewstate2)
        .data("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", stategenerator2)
        .data("__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED", "")
        .data("__EVENTVALIDATION", Eventvalidation2)
        .data("ctl00$Body$COURSES_OFFERED$ctl06$cbox", "on")
        .data("ctl00$Body$RegisterButton", "Register Selected Courses")
        .data("USERNAME_KEY", "USERNAME_VALUE")
        .data("PASSWORD_KEY", "PASSWORD_VALUE")
        .cookies(loginForm.cookies()).post();
```

Some explanation for the code above.

1. First you must make a request to the login page `http://111.68.99.8/StudentProfile/` in order to generate some cookies. These cookies `loginForm.cookies()`, are needed for the actual login.
2. The page includes some other values that must be included in the second request to make it work.
3. You are using android, so you must include the `userAgent` otherwise you are going to send data that correspond to a mobile device and that may be rejected by the site.
4. The confirmation in your case doesn't affect you. By hard coding the values that are needed you do the job, that otherwise would have been done by the javascript running behind the scenes.

In general, the only way to be sure that you are sending all the data that are needed is to check the `Network` tab of development tools and see the actual `Request headers`.

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup cannot handle javascript. Selenium, htmlunit is what you are looking for. You can enable javascript in htmlunit webclient and it will help you getting the click as the htmlunit's webclient mimics all the behaviours of a web browser.